# Why does -1*List object return an empty list?

Tags: python-3.6

I was trying some operations on the List object and wanted to see some "broadcast" behavior :

```
 x = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 x = -1*x

In [46]: x

Out[46]: []
```

I was expecting something like `x = [1, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]`.

What is actually happening?

Answer (score 4):

You can only this kind of multiplication with a pandas `Series` (or better the underlaying `numpy` array). If you write something like

```
List = n * List
```

with `n` as an integer your list gets resized by `n`:

```
x = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
x = 3*x
print(x)

>> [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And negative numbers will remove your list entries (treated as 0 - see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)).

> Values of `n` less than `0` are treated as `0` (which yields an empty
>   sequence of the same type as `s`).

So you have to use one of these methods to multiply each list element:

```
NewList = [i * 5 for i in List]

for i in List:
    NewList.append(i * 5)

import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(List)
NewList = (s * 5).tolist()
```

Comment: ...not only for `pandas`. the underlying `numpy` is capable of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as well. and you could create your own data types that support broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

You want the following:

`x = [-1 * i for i in x]`